# NASM (Intel) ASM Error on pop

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Every time I try to compile my code with NASM, where there is a "pop" ("pop al" in this case), it gives me an error.

```
20: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

In line 20, I have

```
pop al
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you even read the manual? Not even the humble 8086 (assumed from `al`) can `push` or `pop` an 8-bit register.

Comment: I would suggest you google for "8086 instruction set", and especially for "adressing mods", and try to understand what all this `r32,r/m32` etc stuff means

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is literally the error message provided by the assembler: *"invalid combination of opcode and operands"*. The [`POP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_248.html) instruction has no `POP r8` encoding possible. In other words, you cannot pop an 8-bit value off the stack

The closest equivalent would be `pop ax`, which uses a `POP r16` encoding to pop a 16-bit value off the stack into the `ax` register. However, this is not exactly the same as your code, because it will modify both the lower 8-bit half (`al`) and the upper 8-bit half (`ah`) of the 16-bit `ax` register.

Another alternative is to load the value directly from the stack, using something like `mov al, BYTE PTR [(r/e)sp]`. Because this does not alter the stack pointer, you will need to adjust it manually.

---

Next time, please also specify what your target platform is. This is important, because the 16-bit real mode has very limited possibilities for addressing modes, compared to 32-bit and 64-bit protected mode. If you don't specify which mode you're targeting, the answers you get may not work for you. Like here, I have no idea whether that `mov` instruction should use `rsp` (64-bit), `esp` (32-bit), or `sp` (16-bit).